# In-app buttons size

Tags: android, button, icons, size

I'm currently doing some graphical work for an app, and since I never did it before, I'm confused about some icon sizes.

Do the buttons / icons included in the app (not the launcher icon) have to follow the official size guides? Or does it depend on each app in particular? Can I make it any size I want? Or should I make the button in all the dimensions and dpi?

Thanks!

Comment: You can have any size of images, but it totally depends upon your app. while making images just keep most of the size of devices.

Answer (score 1):

> Do the buttons / icons included in the app (not the launcher icon)
>   have to follow the official size guides?

No.

> Or does it depend on each app in particular? Can I make it any size I want?

Yes.

> Or should I make the button in all the dimensions and dpi?

Maybe. You probably want to provide images for a couple of different resolutions, but maybe not for *every* one possible. For instance, if you don't target legacy hardware, you may be good with removing the low dpi versions. Android picks the variant of an image that "best" fits its current configuration. If there's no exact match on the dpi it will choose the next best match automatically.

Maybe take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html.